# Camel - data from two sources

Tags: apache-camel

We are using apache Camel for routing and extracting from the files.

I have a situation where I need to get the data from a file on a shared folder and data from database. I need to combine the data only when data from both sides have arrived. If either side has not received then my data combine process should wait till both sides are present.

Is it possible to possible? How can I achieve that? Any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Something must trigger the process - either the file or the database so pick one.

Then you can use the [enricher pattern](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) to populate the other source (when data is ready). An aggregation strategy is used to combine the data. You typically write the aggregation strategy in java.

The link has examples how to enrich and merge data. You can find out how to handle database and files in the Camel documentation.

Comment: Using aggregation strategy, say file has arrived and camel process is kicked but database rows have not. In that case, I want to wait and start polling until database rows have also arrived. Would that be possible? Sorry if I am asking silly question despite you have given the link above. I want both things to happen in single camel context.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for zip processed file with processing log together. I attached an example, hope it will help you.

```
//Archived
    from("direct:" + EnvironmentSetup.ARCHIVED)
      .routeId(ROUTES.ARCHIVED.name())
        .setHeader(HEADER_ZIP_AGG_ID, header(Exchange.FILE_NAME))
        .setHeader(HEADER_AFTER_ZIP_DEST).constant(getArchiveUri())
        .setHeader(HEADER_STATUS).constant(STATUS.SUCCESS)
        .pipeline()
          .to("direct:" + EnvironmentSetup.ARCHIVED_ZIP)
        .end()
        .pipeline()
          .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).append(".report"))
          .setBody(header(ProcessManager.PROCESS_LOG).convertToString())
          .to("direct:" + EnvironmentSetup.ARCHIVED_ZIP)
        .end()
    .end();

    from(
        "direct:" + EnvironmentSetup.DECRYPT_FAILED_ZIP,
        "direct:"+EnvironmentSetup.PROCESS_FAILED_ZIP,
        "direct:"+EnvironmentSetup.ARCHIVED_ZIP
    )
        .routeId("ZIP")
          .aggregate(header(HEADER_ZIP_AGG_ID), new CopiedGroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
            .completionSize(2)
            .marshal(zipFileDataFormat)
              .multicast()
                .pipeline()
                  .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple(String.format(
                      "${in.header.%s}/${in.header.%s}", HEADER_EMAIL, Exchange.FILE_NAME))) //header(HEADER_EMAIL). header(Exchange.FILE_NAME))
                  //.dynamicRouter(header(HEADER_AFTER_ZIP_DEST))
                  .to("direct:dynamic")

                .end()
                .pipeline()
                  .marshal(encryption)
                  .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple(String.format(
                      "${in.header.%s}/${in.header.%s}.gpg", HEADER_EMAIL, Exchange.FILE_NAME)))
                  //.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).append(".gpg"))
                  .to("direct:"+EnvironmentSetup.SEND_BACK)
                .end()
          .end() //end aggregate
        .end();
```

**CopiedGroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy.java**

```
public class CopiedGroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy extends
                                                      AbstractListAggregationStrategy<Exchange> {

    @Override
    public boolean isStoreAsBodyOnCompletion() {
        // keep the list as a property to be compatible with old behavior
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Exchange getValue(Exchange exchange) {
        return exchange.copy();
    }

}
```